# Quickly going from * wild card to a few specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Let's say I have 20 columns in a table and I run a manual query like:

```
  SELECT *

  FROM [TABLE]

  WHERE [PRODUCT] LIKE '%KRABBY PADDY%'
```

After viewing the results, I realize I only need 10 of those columns. Is there a quick way to list out the 10 columns you want, something like right clicking on the wild card and somehow selecting the columns you want?

Comment: no, you have to specify the column names explicitly.

Comment: There are third party tools, like `sql prompt`, that can do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right clicking the `*` and selecting the columns doesn't sound terribly fast either. 
You can use SSMS to go to the table, and drag the "Columns":

[image]

You'll get every column, and then you can keep the ones you want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do exactly what you are asking for, but in SQL Server Management Studio you can obtain the SELECT statement with all the columns of a table by right-clicking he table on the object explorer an select the options:

> **script table as** --> **SELECT to** --> **Clipboard**

Once you have this SELECT is prety easy to eliminate the columns you don't need on the SELECT

Comment: I think you mean `script table as`

Answer (score 1):

Another SSMS solution:

- Highlight the query.
- Right click it, choose "Design Query In Editor".
- The query designer will automatically expand the `*` to a column list.
- As you tick and untick the columns you want in the top panel, the text of the query in the bottom panel will change to match.
- Hit "OK" and it'll write the new query over the old text in the editor.

I've not used this much myself (I generally just type) but it seems to work fine for simple queries.

[image]